# How can i get the user current location and put marker on it in android by using google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

i develop the application that has Google API so i can put map in my app
i have problem in get user Current location, i want : 
when the user open map Activity it display the map and marker on her location.i already doing google API stuff but i faced problem with USER CURRENT LOCATION AND MARKER ON IT.
 this is my code(it is shows me in ocean !!):
        alert.setButton2("get an address",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

```
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(
                                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                            try {
                                List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,1);
                                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem( touchedPoint, "Whats up", "2nd String");
                                CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d,MapsActivity.this);
                                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                                overlaylist.add(custom);
                                if (address.size() > 0) {
                                    String display = "";
                                    for (int i = 0; i < address.get(0)
                                            .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                        display += address.get(0)
                                                .getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                                    }

                                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(
                                            getBaseContext(), display,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    t.show();

                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

i Have a nightmare about Map, PLEASE FIX MY CODE

Answer (score 0):

please check below example

1) http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html

2) http://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/map-marker-dragging

in second one you can check how to get address.

Thank You

Comment: i tried with Second Link it does not work,please be sure before you answer

Comment: @user1257040 -- if you checked properly then you can understand that 1) it shows map
2) it check user location & center the map to that location
3) marker pin is at the center of map (in xml) 
from point 2 & 3 you can see that marker is at the user location.

Comment: i swaer i checke the second Link, and run it but it is just show me the map, so which link will give me all the steps?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to show users current location you could use MyLocationOverlay class in mapactivity.
it will draw the marker on the location itself.

Comment: MyLocationOverlay is it just for marker or also will show me where the i am ?

Comment: It will show your current location on map with a marker. It just requires permission for location in manifest

Comment: what about OverlayItem ? does it doing the same thing?

Comment: no..in it you will have to give location where you want the marker.It helps to mark multiple points